# How to alternate background colour every other div in PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently working on creating a website with a blogging platform, and I want every other post container on the home page to alternate colours. Like light blue, then dark blue, light blue, dark blue, light blue, etc. I'm using a while loop to get 5 posts from the mysql database. Here is my code.

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6");
$array = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

//The php below this is the problem

$counter = 0;
$counter++;

$postcolour =  WHAT DO I PUT HERE ? 'lightblue' : 'darkblue';


?>


<div class="postcontainer" style="background-color: <?php echo $postcolour; ?>;">
</div> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: a) You wouldn't want your counter to reset inside the loop b) The modulo operator is what you're looking for: `$postcolour = $counter % 2 == 0 ? 'lightblue' : 'darkblue';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) two:

```
$postcolour = $counter % 2 ? 'lightblue' : 'darkblue';
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect. I also needed to move $counter++ inside the loop and move $counter = 0; out of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just use CSS:

```css
.postcontainer {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.postcontainer:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: darkblue;
}
```

[Here's a demo!](http://dabblet.com/gist/3711119)